# What was the standard spoken language (dialect) in the Three Kingdoms period?

Tags: language, ancient-china

Mandarin is the standard spoken language (dialect) in today's China, meaning distinct regions may have their own dialect, but they can all use Mandarin to communicate with each other.

Since all languages evolve, as a contemporary Cantonese speaker, I would have difficulty understanding Cantonese conversations from just two hundred years ago. How would a conversation between Cao Cao and Liu Bei have sounded like? What standard dialect would they have been using?

Edit: This question is about the history of "[standard spoken language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Chinese#History)" which refers to standardized languages used for official purposes in China. This question is not about the history of many vernacular languages spoke throughout history in China.

Comment: Given the situation today (i.e. regions having their own dialects), is there any reason to presume that in the past, when broad communication was more difficult, the situation would have been more uniform? As to how the language actually sounded, I'm guess that no one really knows. Much like in Europe, we don't really know how the Romans spoke. The language has survived but we have no way of proving that the way it's pronounced today would be recognisable by a Roman 2000 years ago.

Comment: At the time, the bulk of the Han population were in the North China Plain, where travel is extremely easy and populations weren't isolated. Many Chinese dialects did not appear until much later, chiefly in the geographically isolated southern regions.

Comment: I found this Middle Chinese audio, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eemRbc7XGLk I hope it is what I am looking for.

Comment: The three kingdoms were three independent governments in China at that time, and there were only three. Please Google it.

Comment: Wikipedia:  "*Confucius, for example, used yǎyán (雅言; "elegant speech") rather than colloquial regional dialects; text during the Han Dynasty also referred to tōngyǔ (通语; "common language")*". Perhaps if you Baidu 通语 三国 ? Wikipedia doesn't mention standardization again until the Ming. I wonder what the Tang used as a standard dialect?

Comment: @Rathony ["Three Kindoms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Kingdoms) is the name used to describe the period from 220 - 280 AD in China. A popularized version was written a while ago [in a historical novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_of_the_Three_Kingdoms) in 14th century.

Comment: @SteveBird Ignoring stoner distractions like "How do we really know the color I call green is the same color you call green", of course linguists have a pretty good handle on what classical Latin sounded like. They looked down on rhyming, sure, but (to take the single most obvious example) you have a multinational empire writing important people's names in German, Greek, Egyptian, Arabic, Hebrew, etc. You can look at the translations and misspellings to, eg, be certain that the Roman v was actually pronounced /u/ or /w/, the i sometimes intended a /j/ sound but never a hard J, etc.

Comment: @TangHo Middle Chinese was several centuries too late to answer this question.

Comment: @axsvl77 The Chang'an dialect (=Middle Chinese).

Answer (score 14):

> [中國歷代官方語言 (Wikipedia)](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B%E6%AD%B7%E4%BB%A3%E5%AE%98%E6%96%B9%E8%AA%9E%E8%A8%80)
>
> 漢朝的汉语标准语称“正音”、“雅言”，也称“通語”，后来的“天下通语”则用来严格指汉语标准语。揚雄著書《輶軒使者絕代語釋別國方言》，“方言”即與“通語”相對。
>
> 汉代國語為“洛語”，洛語承襲先秦时代的雅言。

There was a standard Chinese dialect during the Han Dynasty and Three Kingdoms. [Yang Xiong](https://www.iep.utm.edu/yangxion/)'s 1st-century [*Light-Carriage Messanger's Explanation of Other Countries' Local Expressions in Times Past*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fangyan) distinguished the empire's **通語 ("common language")** from the **方言** ("dialects") spoken by various regions within and around China. This standard was also known as **正音 ("correct pronunciation"), 雅言 ("elegant speech")**, and later **天下通语 ("universal common language")**. These strictly referred to the standard spoken language for the empire.

The prestige dialect during this time was **洛語 ("Luo")**, the Chinese spoken around the Eastern Zhou and Eastern Han capital Luoyang. In English scholarship, it's usually discussed as **[Eastern Han Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Han_Chinese)** or **[Old Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Chinese)**, although the latter can technically include other dialects going back as early as [Sino-Tibetan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Tibetan_languages). Still, when you see Baxter, Sagart, & al. reconstructing Old Chinese it's usually for the Chang'an (=Xi'an) and Luo dialects that developed into [Middle Chinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle%20Chinese).

The present-day [Luoyang dialect (洛陽話)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luoyang_dialect) has different tones than Mandarin, which is based on the Beijing dialect which became standard during the Ming and Qing dynasties. It also still has the sound /v/ and some different vowels. Old Chinese was very different: its syllables were longer, with many consonant endings, and it probably lacked tones altogether. Nothing in China today is quite like it, but the southern parts of China were settled later and stayed poorer longer so they've preserved some things: 中國 in Mandarin is *Zhōngguó* but in Luo it was probably closer to *Trungkwək* or *Tungkwug*; you can still see traces of that in Cantonese *Zung¹gwok³*, Gan *Zung¹guet⁶*, Hakka *Zung¹guêd⁵*, Eastern Min *Dṳ̆ngguók*, Hokkien *Tiong¹kok⁴*, Shanghainese *Tsonkoq*. You see it in foreign loanwords, too, like Japanese *Chūgoku*, Korean *Jungguk*, and (almost perfectly preserved) Vietnamese *Trungquốc*. It also had a bunch of glottal stops, although they (and the final consonants) were starting to disappear by the Three Kingdoms period.

The *written* form of Old Chinese survived a lot longer so it gets a separate name: [Ancient Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Chinese). Chinese students still have to learn it so they can appreciate almost anything written in the country until the early 20th century. It shows us that Old Chinese also used very different vocabulary and grammar from modern Chinese and (especially in writing) was very terse.

**In conclusion:**

- The standard dialect of the Eastern Han dynasty was Luo, although it was called other names at the time.
- Neither Cao Cao nor Liu Bei grew up in the capital, so they'd use their local dialects informally with old friends. With people from other prefectures or in formal contexts, they would've used Luo.
- You can see the Baxter/Sagart and Zhengzhang reconstructions of Old Chinese pronunciations in most Chinese entries on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/). They're similar but not identical, because we can't be 100% sure what Old Chinese sounded like. [Still, looking at phonetic character radicals, poetry, rhyming dictionaries, misspellings, Chinese dialects, foreign loanwords, &c., linguists can make some very educated guesses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ME8wzyR6pO8). It was something like Vietnamese or Cantonese without tones (*not* because it came from those areas but because those languages have preserved the older forms more, the same way [Shakespearean English sounded more Scottish or Appalachian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQc5ZpAoU4c) than like a present-day Londoner).
- The Luoyang dialect for this period would've been a little softer than those, with some or all of the hard final consonants disappearing.

Comment: The conversation between Cao Cao and Liu Bei would  be between two nobles.

Comment: There's a very good chance that Cao and Liu had different dialect, therefore, 洛語 would be their common language.

Comment: Was 天下通语 during the Han a legal standard like putonghua today? Or just the language that happened to be spoken by the elite?

Comment: *Was 天下通语 during the Han a legal standard like putonghua today?*  It would be, I mean people could use their own dialect among themselves, but when they were speaking to the ruling class, they must use the standard language, just like all Chinese must use Mandarin to deal with government officials in China now.

Comment: @Rathony - I think its reasonable to assume they kept speaking the same language as before in the absence of evidence to the contrary.

Comment: The language itself is so complex most don't bother. In China they work instead. Hence the term "Mandarins" meaning a ruling class that can speak Chinese. I think Dr Sun Yat Sen tried to change that but you would have to look it up.

Comment: Added links and cleaned up the phasing, translations, and grammar. Since this is already a very good answer, rather than write a separate one to compliment it I'll just add in some missing details here (Luo=Luoyang, *why* it would sound like Minnan, etc.) with links.

Comment: Fully expanded with more links, discussion of Old and Ancient Chinese and some examples pulled off of Wiktionary's Zhengzhang transcription list.

Answer (score -1):

I am a hakka and a 61st descendant of Liu Bei. My ancestors settled down south in Hokkien region during the Tang Dynasty. Today, there are now many branches of Liu Bei's descendants in northern Guangdong, where hakka is spoken. My family still speak hakka. My grandfather made it a point that we learnt and *[spoke hakka just like our ancestors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakka_people)*.

My theory is that Liu Bei would have spoken a language similar to hakka or a very old variant of hakka as my family even during the Song dynasty, which is about 1000 years ago, spoke hakka (they never spoke [*Minnan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Min)/Hokkien notwithstanding they were there for almost 400 years before moving south to northern Guangdong).

My good friend is a 27th generation descendant of Zhao Guangyin, the founder of the Song dynasty. They speak a language similar to a cross between Cantonese and Hakka. My friend's ancestral home is in Southern Guangdong.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Given that the ethno-genesis of Hakka is is slightly controversial ([**2003 analysis on Hakka origin**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14577381) by Center for Anthropological Studies at Fudan University, Shanghai) - I wonder if you are quite certain that it was only _early_-Hakka? Could there be other dialects?

Comment: That's cool and all but your family's supposed genealogy isn't an argument for the language's continuity.